# Custom Quality Gate for open source project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I can't find the option to create custom QG on sonarqube.com instance used by my open source GitHub project. Is it non-customisable for open source projects at all?

Answer (score 1):

Currently in SonarQube (6.0 and LTS 5.6 as of this writing), editing Quality Gates (or Quality Profiles) requires a global permission called `Administer Quality Gates` (or `Administer Quality Profiles`). This permission is usually locked down to a few select admins (e.g. on sonarqube.com) as the impact spans across all projects (including those that you do not own).

With respect to Quality Profiles: allowing some users to edit their own profiles is a frequently discussed topic, you should track [SONAR-1330](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-1330) for the full details on this.

Comment: That issue is quite old and I'm not familiar with the history of SonarQube. However, you are talking about Quality Profiles, I about Quality Gates. Are you sure this is managed by the same set permission?

Comment: Duh, just a typo. Answer edited with respective permissions for Gates and Profiles.

Answer (score 1):

I do confirm that this is a known limitation of SonarQube.Com: quality profiles can't be updated. The default "Sonar way" quality profiles which are supposed to be suitable for any kind of projects are used but indeed there is not way to go beyond those default activated rules. Hopefully, this limitation will vanish in several months by having SonarQube.Com supporting the concept of organization/entity.